# Webservices Route

Tags: joomla-api

If I create Route for the API via

```
$router->createCRUDRoutes( 'v1/foos', 'foos', ['component' => 'com_foos'], true );
```

Like explainded in https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32322/7387 the Route is

```
JOOMLA/api/v1/foos
```

I like a Route without the `api` like

```
JOOMLA/v1/foos
```

How do I archive this?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a solution myself. I use a redirect in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /myvalue /api/v1/foos/index.php/myvalue
```

Is there another better way in Joomla?

Comment: I do think it should be possible with .htaccess to mask the `/api` without having to do a redirect, however I couldn't provide you with a working example. Search for  examples of rewriteCond and rewriteRule for ways to add /api to your incoming URI/URL. I use these two lines to append a folder to a URL so what you need to do is insert /api to the URL before /v1.  rewriteCond %{http_HOST} ^www\mydomain\.com\.au$ and then follow it up with  rewriteRule (.*) /site2/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change or remove the `/api` within Joomla as it is hard coded into the processing of the URI found in `libraries/src/Uri/Uri.php`, see code below at the last line.

```
        if (trim($live_site) != '')
        {
            $uri = static::getInstance($live_site);
            static::$base['prefix'] = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'host', 'port'));
            static::$base['path'] = rtrim($uri->toString(array('path')), '/\\');

            if (\defined('JPATH_BASE') && \defined('JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR') && JPATH_BASE == JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR)
            {
                static::$base['path'] .= '/administrator';
            }

            if (\defined('JPATH_BASE') && \defined('JPATH_API') && JPATH_BASE == JPATH_API)
            {
                static::$base['path'] .= '/api';
            }
        }
```

I do think it should be possible with .htaccess to insert the `/api` into the URL for Joomla without having to do a redirect, however I don't have a working example I can provide you with.

Search for  examples of `rewriteCond` and `rewriteRule` for ways to insert `/api` to your incoming URI/URL.

```
rewriteCond %{http_HOST} ^www\mydomain\.com\.au$
rewriteRule (.*) /site2/$1 [L]
```

I use these two lines to append a folder to a URL so what you need to do is insert `/api` to the URL before `/v1`.

Your condition statement would have to be more specific to your API's URL so as not to interfere with other API's in your instance, i.e. you don't want to end up creating `yourdomian/api/api/otherapi`.